# Open source ad votes overflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

Am i the only one who receives this?

[image]

Comment: confirmed; see http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/all

Answer (score 1):

It has 87 votes, and the other ads also start with the real vote count and then concatenates what seems to be a random string (but I suspect it's not random)

**Edit**: Aparently it was the user IDs of the people who posted the ads

Comment: At a glance, those strings look to me like times in `hhmmss` format.

Comment: @Dominic: I'm curious to know what kind of clock you use. For the format to be hhmmss, you're saying that 14:03:81 is a valid time. :)

Comment: @Michael - excellent point. I was looking at the link balpha posted, where many of the numbers under the ads are valid times. Now I look closer, a whole load aren't. Oops.

Comment: Those were the user IDs of the people who posted the ads, but it seems to be fixed now.

Comment: @Michael - Dominic must be using decimal time http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time